# If current_user_can / Else

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out where is my error in the following syntax. I am trying to use the If / Else statement to display contact info to managers and admins and info box in as div to everybody else :

```
    <h2><?php _e( 'Manager Information', 'manager_suite' ); ?></h2>

    <?php if( current_user_can('manager') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> <!--show contact only to admins and managers -->

    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <?php if ( !empty( $store_info['store_name'] ) ) { ?>
            <li class="store-name">
                <span><?php _e( 'Store Name:', 'manager_suite' ); ?></span>
                <span class="details">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $store_info['store_name'] ); ?>
                </span>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>

        <li class="manager-name">
            <span>
                <?php _e( 'Store Contact:', 'manager_suite' ); ?>
            </span>

            <span class="details">
                <?php printf( '<a href="%s">Visit Store</a>', get_store_url( $author->ID ), $author->display_name ); ?>
            </span>
        </li>

        <li class="clearfix">
            <?php get_readable_manager_rating( $author->ID ); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>

    else <!--show this if user is not admin or manager -->
      echo <div class="horizontal-notice">
         You cannot see this manager details.
           </div>

    <?php } ?> <!--show contact only to admins and managers END-->
```

I definitely have several errors in this syntax - most probably with displaying the "Else" statement and also with the `<ul>` . I think the `<div>` is not displayed correctly either.

Can you please help correct my errors ?

Comment: i want to know,  is this a .php file or .html file

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but try replacing $product->post->post_author with $product->post_author

**[UPDATE]**

I didn't notice any error, but now I've seen the ending part of the code that contains some mistakes. Try this code.

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Manager Information', 'manager_suite' ); ?></h2>

<?php if( current_user_can('manager') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> <!--show contact only to admins and managers -->

<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <?php if ( !empty( $store_info['store_name'] ) ) { ?>
        <li class="store-name">
            <span><?php _e( 'Store Name:', 'manager_suite' ); ?></span>
            <span class="details">
                <?php echo esc_html( $store_info['store_name'] ); ?>
            </span>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>

    <li class="manager-name">
        <span>
            <?php _e( 'Store Contact:', 'manager_suite' ); ?>
        </span>

        <span class="details">
            <?php printf( '<a href="%s">Visit Store</a>', get_store_url( $author->ID ), $author->display_name ); ?>
        </span>
    </li>

    <li class="clearfix">
        <?php get_readable_manager_rating( $author->ID ); ?>
    </li>
</ul>

<?php } else { ?> <!--show this if user is not admin or manager -->
  <div class="horizontal-notice">
     You cannot see this manager details.
  </div>

<?php } ?> <!--show contact only to admins and managers END-->
```

Comment: Thanks Flavio, the code runs perfectly displaying the contact information without the If / Else statements, so nothing wrong there. I think my problem there is positioning the `<ul>` within the php.

It should probably be something like echo `"<ul class="list-unstyled">"` but, just ca'n figure this out. Also maybe the first `<?php` with the `If current_user_can` should not be closed ?

Comment: Hmmm I can't see any error... can you provide a pastebin with the interpreted code (view source from browser)?

Comment: Pastebin currently overloaded..

There must be something wrong with the `else` statement. It cannot stand on it's own just like this. It showing up as text. Shouldn't it be wrapped in php tags or something ?

Answer (score 1):

also your **else** statement is not even been looked at Try this (just posting the end part of ul)

```
</ul>

<?php
} else{ ?>
    <!--show this if user is not admin or manager -->
  <div class="horizontal-notice">
    You cannot see this manager details.
</div>

<?php } ?>  <!--show contact only to admins and managers END-->
```

Comment: Working ! That is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't figure out how to fit the else statement into the php tags.

Thanks Luke, you made my day !

Answer (score 1):

```
  echo <div class="horizontal-notice">
     You cannot see this manager details.
       </div>
```

Your echo statement creates a syntax error. Try surrounding it by `'`s